# Extract image from a m4a file?

Tags: music

I already tried `eyeD3`, but that doesn't work for m4a files, and If I convert the m4a to mp3 format, I lose the image.

What other choice do I have?

Comment: If you're referring to Apple's music files, I can drag the artwork from iTunes onto my Mac desktop.

Comment: @KyleJones I don't have a Mac hmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `mp4art`, part of the [mp4v2 project](https://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/). On Ubuntu, you can find it in the `mp4v2-utils` package.

```
mp4art --extract mysong.m4a
```

should extract the covr-box. See [the docs](http://mp4v2.googlecode.com/svn/doc/1.9.0/ToolGuide.html#TOC6) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution using `ffmpeg`:

1. Find the ID of the stream we want to extract (`0:1`):

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i input.mp3
   ...
       Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
       Stream #0:1: Video: png, rgba(pc), 190x190, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
   ...
   ```
2. Extract the stream using the `-map` option:

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -map 0:1 output.png
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The cover can be extracted with the [TagEditor project](//github.com/Martchus/tageditor):

```
tageditor -e cover -o y.jpg -f z.m4a
```